# Why can't I add a package (module) I created in Julia?

Tags: visual-studio-code, package, julia

I am having trouble installing a module I created in Julia. I am running the Julia plugin under Visual Studio Code. If I run the file below with Ctrl+F5 I get a message

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Utils not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Utils")` to install the Utils package.
```

This is the file:

```
module demo

using Utils

greet() = print("Hello World!")

end # module
```

If I follow the advice on the error message I get another error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Utils (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

I also tried inserting this line:

```
import Pkg; Pkg.add(path="C:/Dropbox/Code/Julia/demo/src/Utils.jl")
```

and got this message (although the path definitely exists):

```
ERROR: LoadError: Path `C:/Dropbox/Code/Julia/demo/src/Utils.jl` does not exist.
```

The files `demo.jl` and `Utils.jl` are in `C:\Dropbox\Code\Julia\demo\src\` and the `demo` project has been activated as can be seen in the REPL. The OS is Windows 10 Pro.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Lots of time wasted trying to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module and packages are not the same things. In short, packages are modules plus a set of metadata that make it easy for the package to be found and interact well with other packages. See here for a tutorial to write Julia packages:
https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/11-developing-julia-packages

In your case, if you want to load a local *module*, just type `include("fileWhereThereIsTheModule.jl")` followed by a `using Main.MyModule` or `using .MyModule`. Note the dot... without it, Julia would indeed look for a package and to let it find your `Demo` or `Util` module you would have to either change an environmental variable or place your module file in certain predefined folders. Using `include` followed by the "absolute or relative position" of the module you don't have to do either.

Comment: Many thanks. Works perfectly. But I am puzzled because I managed to make two modules work while just trying different things. I cannot repeat the procedure, which did not include any one of your two suggestions. I tried again today and managed to do it once and tried a third time and failed no matter how many things I tried. So, as you say, there is another way. I noticed that the packages I installed do not show up in Project.toml or in Manifest.toml. So I will read the material you suggested and maybe then I will understand. Thanks again.

Comment: I looked at the tutorial you suggested. It is useful but I could not understand it completely. It seems to contradict your suggestion: 'Note: using and import, when they are followed with either Main.x or .x, look for a module already loaded and bring it and its exported objects into scope (for import only those explicitly specified). Otherwise, they do a completely different job: they expects a package, and the package system lookups the correct version of the module x embedded inside package x'. The packages imported following your suggestion are neither already loaded nor in any package.

Comment: I don't see why the two contradict. Are you trying to just build a module or a whole package? For a package you need to provide a certain folder structure and the `Project.toml` file, while for a module you just write the file with the module content.. you can also put multiple modules in yhe same file... `include` will already "load" the module in the given file but then you need to stiil use `using` or `import`..

Comment: You are right. My bad.

Comment: I am now trying to add Indicators.jl from Github. So I did ```add Indicators```. It did not work and told me to do ```Pkg.precompile()```. One dependency did not precompile, maybe due to the ```include``` statement:
```Failed to precompile demo [a6a479a7-4f43-4bd5-b6d9-b84bd8e9cf8a] to C:\Users\fsald\.julia\compiled\v1.6\demo\jl_16C4.tmp.
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: include not defined```. Is the ```include``` "guilty"?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code. Did you try to restart Julia after having added the package ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to install Indicators starting from a file that did not have an ``ìnclude``` statement. Now I have a similar problem with ```Infiltrator.jl```.

Comment: If you're creating packages, you should nearly always do it with PkgTemplates.jl: https://invenia.github.io/PkgTemplates.jl/stable/user/